# Building angular app for production

Tags: angular

I am new to angular.I have just created an app using node-oracledb to connect to oracle db and fetch data. The app is working. Now i need to move the project to production, what i need to do to built the app for production.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Angular-cli, it's:

```
ng build --prod
```

You can read more in the [angular-cli Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build)

Answer (score 0):

Build production package using this command (AngularCli project),

```
ng build --aot --prod
```

**--aot  flag will increase the performance of the build.**

This command will generate new folder by name of **dist** (distribution folder). 
Your dist folder is your final build.

If you want to deploy in **Apache server** then do the following steps.

1. Create new Dynamic webproject in eclipse or any other IDE.
2. Copy dist folder Files and past in Dynamic web project's **WebContent** folder.
3. Export the project as war file and deploy in Apache server.

Comment: Building to prod automatically sets the --aot flag to true

Comment: @Carsten - I aware , Even though we found huge difference between two commands in production build.  Build reduced 56 to 12 seconds with --aot . So i suggesting that manual --aot flag